# What is the correct way to write an SQL statement to push data rows for this array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to push array data to a MySQL database using foreach().  I'm quite a novice at PHP & mysql, so been working through parsing this data to PHP from an Ajax script, now just need to manipulate the data.

What is the correct syntax to push this data into SQL so that each dataset in the array goes to a seperate row?

i am trying to use foreach, but the complexity is that the array itself can change in size and the second complexity is that the data itself may be refreshed (i.e same id new values on a new day), so I want to build in some intelligence to update info not just append; and also to backup old data to another table.

is this syntax correct?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES ";
foreach($rows as $i=>$row) {
    if ($i>0) {
        $sql .= sprintf(",(%s,%s)", $row["col1_value"], $row["col2_value"]);
    } else {
        $sql .= sprintf("(%s,%s)", $row["col1_value"], $row["col2_value"]);
    }
}
mysql_query($sql);
```

The data in the array is as follows - this is only part of a multidimensional array, but I have figured out how to manipulate the rest of the array to my needs.

The only other thing I need to do is figure out a way to take the coords field and manipulate it as follows

Extract x & y data from coords
Multiple x & y by 600/386
Reverse x & y and take the first digit of each coordinate to create a new value y[1]x[1].

For this I tried just on the first data set, as follows, but I am inexperienced in data handling on PHP.  Pretty sure it is wrong.

```
$testcoords = $_POST['data'][0]['coords'];
list($x,$y) = explode(“:”,str_replace(“’”,“”,$testcoords));
$xtrans = number_format($x*600/386,$decimals=null);
$ytrans = number_format($y*600/386,$decimals=null);
$cont = “C”.$ytrans[0].$xtrans[0]
```

So to summarize, three questions

1. How do I transfer data into a table, with rows for each individual dataset in the [data] array?
2. How do overwrite and archive any existing values in the table rather than simply concatenating?
3. How do I manipulate one specific string to return a custom variable as defined above?

   ```
   [data_type] => city
   [data] => Array
       (
           [0] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 16515340
                   [owner_id] => 3475
                   [owner] => Player1
                   [coords] => '268:252
                   [name] => AC2013
                   [score] => 11863
                   [city_type] => castle
                   [location] => land
               )

           [1] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 16515335
                   [owner_id] => 3475
                   [owner] => Player1
                   [coords] => '263:252
                   [name] => AC2013
                   [score] => 7
                   [city_type] => castle
                   [location] => water
               )

           [2] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 17891610
                   [owner_id] => 3523
                   [owner] => Player2
                   [coords] => '282:273
                   [name] => City of Repoman9900
                   [score] => 1978
                   [city_type] => castle
                   [location] => water
               )

           [3] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 10616856
                   [owner_id] => 73
                   [owner] => Player2
                   [coords] => '024:162
                   [name] => 1killer
                   [score] => 1308
                   [city_type] => castle
                   [location] => water
               )

           [4] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 10813465
                   [owner_id] => 2862
                   [owner] => Player3
                   [coords] => '025:165
                   [name] => City of vuvuzea991
                   [score] => 1091
                   [city_type] => castle
                   [location] => land
               )

           [5] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 17367317
                   [owner_id] => 84
                   [owner] => Player4
                   [coords] => '277:265
                   [name] => Dreadland
                   [score] => 776
                   [city_type] => castle
                   [location] => water
               )

           [6] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 2162850
                   [owner_id] => 2989
                   [owner] => Player5
                   [coords] => '162:033
                   [name] => City of Dinoeyez
                   [score] => 157
                   [city_type] => castle
                   [location] => water
               )

           [7] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 2818192
                   [owner_id] => 556
                   [owner] => Player6
                   [coords] => '144:043
                   [name] => City of wildfire123
                   [score] => 7
                   [city_type] => castle
                   [location] => water
               )

       )

   [sender] => Array
       (
           [world] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 232
                   [name] => Server 4 
                   [number] => NaN
               )

           [alliance] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 2
                   [name] => Alliance2
               )

           [player] => Array
               (
                   [id] => 98
                   [name] => SuperUser
               )

           [browser] => Array
               (
                   [type] => Chrome
                   [version] => 25.0.1364.160
               )

           [aix_version] => 1.00
       )
   ```

   )

Answer (score 0):

The problems I see:

```
foreach($rows as $i=>$row) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES ";  //reinitialize here.
      if ($i>0) {  //Why have the if statement, the results of the conditions are the same.
        $sql .= sprintf("('%s','%s')", $row["col1_value"], $row["col2_value"]);  //add quotation marks for string values, remove the comma.
      } else {
        $sql .= sprintf("(%s,%s)", $row["col1_value"], $row["col2_value"]);
      }
      mysql_query($sql); //execute the statement here.
   }
```

Your other questions:

> How do overwrite and archive any existing values in the table rather than simply concatenating?

To overwrite you do an update statement, the MySql website gives hints to syntax.

To archive, you will need to create an archive table that is pretty much a duplicate of the table being archived and insert/update that table.

In this context, I am not sure what you mean by concatenation, it does not really apply to databases that are normalized.

> How do I manipulate one specific string to return a custom variable as defined above?

Ah gonna skip that one, it is a lot to ask in one post.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Do you have thoughts on the other 2 parts to my question?